# registerstartupscript blocking javascript character counter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i'm having issues with code that used to work, but now fails to run. I have a character counter on a textbox with the below code in the .aspx file:

```
<script>
    var bName = navigator.appName;
    function taLimit(taObj, maxL) {
        if (taObj.value.length == maxL) return false;
        return true;
    }

    function taCount(taObj, Cnt, maxL) {
        objCnt = createObject(Cnt);
        objVal = taObj.value;
        if (objVal.length > maxL) objVal = objVal.substring(0, maxL);
        if (objCnt) {
            if (bName == "Netscape") {
                objCnt.textContent = maxL - objVal.length;
            }
            else { objCnt.innerText = maxL - objVal.length; }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function createObject(objId) {
        if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
        else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
        else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
        else return eval("document." + objId);
    }
                    </script>
```

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Font-Names="Courier New" 
TextMode="MultiLine" Width="398px" onKeyPress="return taLimit(this, 50)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myCounter1', 50)"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><B><SPAN id='myCounter1'>50</SPAN></B>
```

This worked without problems before, but now i want a way to update the myCounter1 On page load, to show the correct remaining characters, i'm loading text from database into the textbox.

right now i'm using this:

```
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "document.getElementById('myCounter1').textContent = 50 - " + txtDescription.Text.Length.ToString() + ";", true);
```

This works, it sets the character counter to the correct remaining characters. Now the issue is however, when text is typed in the textbox, the caracter counter won't update anymore dynamically. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Would you like to use jQUery? makes life easier

Comment: My knowledge of jquery is really nonexistant now, and i have to fix this asap.

Comment: Can I give you a jQUery Solution

Comment: I'd be really thankful if you did! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using js. Put this inside your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    taCount(document.getElementById('<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>'),'myCounter1', 50);
}
</script>
```

Remove the Server side scriptmanager code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my issue! Can't believe i didn't think of this.